# How to read JSON in a javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file (request.js), and i need to access an external JSON file in the same request.js file.

I know we can use XMLHttpRequest Object and do an ajax call. But my request.js is out of the HTML dom, which handles the transaction. So I cannot use XMLHttpRequest object here.

I am not using jquery as well. So $.get is also out of the box.

Is there anyway to achieve this ? I need to parse the JSON object after reading it from a external json file.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *out of the HTML DOM*?

Comment: request.js file is a seperate js file not associated with any html page. So I am not able to use XMLHttpRequest object

Comment: You mean read local json file on the disk in javascript ?? But how will the javascript execute without HTML ??

Comment: Are you looking for the [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function? [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) provides a shim for browsers with no support.